# How to make a new dict from two dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to build a new dict from dict of just keys and a another dict of keys values pairs. In the second dict there could be more then one item mapped to same key. In the new dict, I would like to collect all those items together in a list and map it to a key. I have this code so far but it doesn't work. I get `KeyError: '1'`.

```
dictKeys = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']

#dict to sort based on dictKeys 
result = {'2': 'Berat', 
          '3': 'Ayn Daflah', 
          '4': 'Eastern', 
          '5': 'Canillo', 
          '1': 'Badgis', 
          '4': "Manu'a", 
          '5': 'Andorra la Vella', 
          '1': 'Badakhshan', 
          '2': 'Bulqize', 
          '3': 'Ayn Tamushanat'}

#expected dictonary
result_dict = {}

for k in dictKeys:
    for key,value in result.items():
        if k == key:
            result_dict[key].append(value)

print result_dict
```

I'm expecting to build a dict like this:

```
{
  '1': ['Badgis', 'Badakhshan'],
  '2': ['Berat', 'Bulqize'],
  '3': ['Ayn Tamushanat', 'Ayn Daflah'],
  '4': ["Manu'a", 'Eastern'],
  '5': ['Canillo', 'Andorra la Vella']    
}
```

Comment: You can never have `result` object like that. There are several repeating keys in it. You might want a list of tuples instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list of tuples instead:

```
result = [('2', 'Berat'), ('3', 'Ayn Daflah'), ('4', 'Eastern'), ('5', 'Canillo'), ('1', 'Badgis'), ('4', "Manu'a"), etc. ]
```

Then do something like this:

```
dictionary = {}

for (key, val) in result:
    if not key in dictionary:
          dictionary[key] = [val]
    else:
        dictionary[key] = dictionary[key] + [val]
```

Comment: ... or much shorter: `for k, v in result: dictionary.setdefault(k, []).append(v)`

Comment: Oooh I like it SuperSaiyan

Comment: Thanks for pointing in right direction guys. Just starting out with python. Didn't realise such a thing is not a possible

Comment: FWIW I usually use `collections.defaultdict(list)` rather than `setdefault` in cases like that, although `setdefault` was great before `defaultdict`s became standard.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper collections.defaultdict doesn't have attribute append, so I guess I cannot use it?

Comment: @jas: `dictionary = collections.defaultdict(list); dictionary[k].append(v)`